# How to impliment pathStorage samelike sessionStorage for browser?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

As i read about sessionStorage and localStorage i want same like pathStorage.

Some where i saw and to override Storage like this,

```
Storage.prototype._setItem = Storage.prototype.setItem;
Storage.prototype.setItem = function(key, value)
{
_key = window.location.pathname + ":" + key;
this._setItem(_key, value);
}

Storage.prototype._getItem = Storage.prototype.getItem;
Storage.prototype.getItem = function(key)
{
_key = window.location.pathname + ":" + key;
return this._getItem(_key);
}
```

But the problem with this it overides for localstorage and session storage only.

where I want a new kinda pathStorage without overriding of localStorage and sessionStorage.

Comment: What is your actual question though?

Comment: create pathStorage where key can be only accessed where it's been created.